# Removing React Query Batch mode

Tags: javascript, reactjs, networking, graphql, react-query

React query seems to batch my requests before they go out.
They do not fire to server independently.
As well they return at the same time.
perhaps under the hook it does a Promise.all().

Any thoughts?
On how to avoid this.
For context, a page is firing 100 requests.

Comment: react-query does no batching of requests.